# How to skip specific Execution Plan Steps?

Tags: deployit, xl-deploy

In the [TaskBlockService](https://docs.xebialabs.com/generated/xl-deploy/5.5.x/rest-api/com.xebialabs.deployit.engine.api.TaskBlockService.html) there is a `POST` call *[that one or more steps should be skipped](https://docs.xebialabs.com/generated/xl-deploy/5.5.x/rest-api/com.xebialabs.deployit.engine.api.TaskBlockService.html#/tasks/v2/%7Btaskid%7D/skip:POST)*. There is not a good example given how the posted XML (List of String) *the paths of the steps to skip*.

Tried the following content for the POSTed data:

```
curl  -X POST  https://xldeploy.company.com/deployit/tasks/v2/5e917094-d054-4cc7-940e-89d851ca225a/skip
```

File `remove-steps.xml` content - sample 1:

```
<list>
    <string>0_1_1</string>
</list>
```

File `remove-steps.xml` content - sample 2:

```
<list>
    <string>0-1-1</string>
</list>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first format you list is right, but you have to make sure you're using a step path and not just the path to a block.

Lets say you get the blocks from your deployment plan with this call.

```
curl -uadmin:password http://localhost:4516/deployit/tasks/v2/28830810-5104-4ab9-9826-22f66dee265d
```

This will produce the result:

```
<task id="28830810-5104-4ab9-9826-22f66dee265d" failures="0" state="PENDING" owner="admin">
  <description>Initial deployment of Environments/local/TestApp001</description>
  <activeBlocks/>
  <metadata>
    <environment>local</environment>
    <taskType>INITIAL</taskType>
    <environment_id>Environments/local</environment_id>
    <application>TestApp001</application>
    <version>1.0</version>
  </metadata>
  <block id="0" state="PENDING" description="" root="true">
    <block id="0_1" state="PENDING" description="Deploy" phase="true">
      <block id="0_1_1" state="PENDING" description="Deploy TestApp001 1.0 on environment local"/>
    </block>
  </block>
  <dependencies/>
```

If you want to see the steps in block 0_1_1 then you can use this rest call to get the steps.

```
curl -uadmin:password http://local6/deployit/tasks/v2/28830810-5104-4ab9-9826-22f66dee265d/block/0_1_1/step

<block id="0_1_1" state="PENDING" description="Deploy TestApp001 1.0 on environment local" current="0">
  <step failures="0" state="PENDING" description="Execute Command"/>
  <step failures="0" state="PENDING" description="Copy File001.txt to Infrastructure/localhost"/>
```

The steps are numbered within the block starting from 1.  So if you are want to skip the step -  Copy File001.txt to Infrastructure/localhost the step path is 0_1_1_2.  Your XML will look like:

```
<list>
    <string>0_1_1_2</string>
</list>
```