# Skip multiple steps, in multiple blocks from execution plan

Tags: rest, deployit, xl-deploy

In [How to skip specific Execution Plan Steps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43634234/how-to-skip-specific-execution-plan-steps/43777001#43777001) an answer is provided to skip steps from a single path block. The example provided in xml worked out to skip a single step or multiple steps for one single block. However, I want to skip multiple steps, in multiple blocks. For instance my xml would look like:

```
<list>
    <string>0_1_1_1_1</string>
    <string>0_1_1_2_1</string>
    <string>0_1_1_2_2</string>  
</list>
```

When I execute a curl command to skip these tasks(/skip), supplemented by the xml file, the following message is retured:

```
Wrong paths Buffer(BlockPath(0_1_1_1_1), BlockPath(0_1_1_2_1), BlockPath(0_1_1_2_2))
```

Interestingly, Only the first item 0_1_1_1_1 is being skipped, the other ones are ignored. Do I need to adjust my xml syntax, or is there another way to skip a complete list of steps inside multiple blocks?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work to skip steps from multiple phases.  You would need to have a rest call for each block with a corresponding xml file.